# "I am to blame for not getting the project" vs "I am to blame to not get the project"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, transitivity

The question is about a situation where I was wrong and made a mistake when a meeting happened, and thus we couldn't get the project.

> "I am to blame for not getting the project"

Is that the correct way to say this?

All I want to know is get through between **"I am to blame**, **I am to be blamed**, **I blame myself."** or **"I blame on me"** I just want to get same meaning with *"It's my fault."*
"For not getting, not for getting, to not get, not to get."
What's the difference those phrases?

Answer (score 1):

> I am to blame for not getting the project.

This is a grammatically correct sentence to answer your first question. You are claiming that you are the one responsible for the group not being able to get the project.

> I am to blame.

This means you are at fault or are responsible for something.

> I am to be blamed.

This is the exact same thing as the last one, but it incorporates an infinitive phrase. Meaning is the same.

> I blame myself.

This means you are PERSONALLY putting the blame on yourself. It's like saying "I put myself at fault" or "I am responsible for this".

> I blame on me.

This is not a grammatically correct sentence. But you could say:

> I blame **it** on me.

All four of those sentences essentially say that you are at fault. **You** are claiming responsibility.

Comment: "I am to be blamed" is more passive than the other grammatically correct options.  This difference changes the meaning.  "I am to be blamed" implies that someone else will blame me -- and it might not be fair to do so.